# Xamarin.Forms front-end logs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mobile, frontend

Is there some way to see the logs of the Xamarin.Forms front-end?

I am somewhat familiar with Blazor, and typically you can see front-end errors by opening the `Developer Tools => Console` in the browser. There you will see errors and warnings, that typically would not manifest themselves in the debugging environment within C# or VS (as far as I am aware).

I am looking for an equivalent in Xamarin.Forms.

A specific example of where I would want this, is exceptions related to binding, in the view's .xaml file.

In my CategoryPage.xaml file, I am binding a hex color code, to the variable `ColorCode`:

```html
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorCode}" Padding="20">
```

Assuming everything else is working correctly, if I have an incorrect color hex value for the `ColorCode` variable I am binding, the `BackgroundColor` would default to *white*.

Looking at the symptomatic manifestation of the problem (a *white* `BackgroundColor` instead of whatever other color I expect), it may be hard to know the root cause.

Therefore, I'm looking for some log, that displays front-end exceptions, along the lines of "**Error: Could not parse hex value 9C27B0"**, in the scenario I have described.

This would indicate to me that the binding *does* occur, but that I have an incorrect value in my repository. Instead of the front-end failing silently.

Comment: In my experience, Binding problems show up in VS Output pane, when debugger is attached. That shows the real-time device logging. A xamarin app is just an app; there isn't anywhere else that logging could be shown.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `Hex color` starts with a pound sign or hashtag (#) and are followed by six letters (A-F) and/or number (digit from 0-9). Alphabetic characters may be uppercase or lowercase. So the `ColorCode` should follow this rule to make it valid.

Furthermore, you can use `Regex` to check whether a given string is a **valid** Hex code or not and then use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/forefront-2010/ms698739(v=vs.100)) to display it in the VS Output panel. I used a invalid data:`#EFFA07A` and it can be shown in the VS Output panel like below:

[image]

Here's the code below for your reference:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{

    
        private string _color;

        public Color ColorCode
        {

            get => Color.FromHex(_color);
            set
            {
                if (!(Regex.Match(_color, "^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$").Success))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: Could not parse hex value: ");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Color.FromHex(_color) == value) return;

                    var a = Color.FromHex(_color); 
                    a = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorCode));

                }
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            ColorCode = Color.FromHex(_color = "#EFFA07A");

            BindingContext =  this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Divan May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions. Please help accept it as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!